# Is there a Spanish idiom equivalent to the English "I'd rather stick pins in my eyes"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, modismos, solicitud-de-modismo

My Spanish colleague invited me to do something I'd prefer not to do. Is there something I could say in response, as an equivalence to the English idiom?

Comment: You can pretty much say anything that sounds bad, in all languages. The more creative and on-topic, the better!

Comment: With a Mexican colleague, "ni madres"

Comment: What’s wrong with saying ¡Prefería clavarme imperdibles en los ojos! The figurative part comes from the exaggeration, not the semantics, so I expect anything would get lost in translation. There’s a Romanian guy on a TV show I watch who does this (for example, one time his wife was dropping snacks in the bed, and he said You’re so messy! What, do you have holes in your hands? which I’ve never heard in English, but it makes perfect sense) and I’ve always thought it makes him look creative and funny.

Comment: This expression is very, very rare in English. Ergo, using common Spanish truisms here **as if** they were that is not an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options for this. One short, common choice is just a plain *[ni muerto](https://dle.rae.es/muerto)* ("not even dead").

> —¿Te vienes a hacer *[puenting](https://dle.rae.es/puenting)* con nosotros?
>   —Ni muerto.

Starting from this you have several other options, such as *[ni loco](https://dle.rae.es/loco)* ("not even crazy").

> —¿Te vienes a hacer *puenting* con nosotros?
>   —Ni loco.

Those two choices are included in the DLE, but here is when creativity comes to help. One common choice used where I live is *ni harto vino* ("not even drunk", the *h* pronounced as in English to emphasize):

> —¿Te vienes a hacer *puenting* con nosotros?
>   —Ni harto vino.

(Note that this last one is a very colloquial option and it may cause quite a laughter if someone that is learning the language uses it. You can use instead the more common *[ni borracho](https://dle.rae.es/borracho)*, literally "not even drunk".)

Some different choices are *[y un cuerno](https://dle.rae.es/cuerno)* and *[y un carajo](https://dle.rae.es/carajo)*, being the former more colloquial and the latter rude and a bit harsh.

> —¿Te vienes a hacer *puenting* con nosotros?
>   —Y un cuerno.

Apart from these expressions, you can just translate the original sentence, I think it would be understood. What's important here is the structure of the sentence to use. I recommend using the *[antes](https://dle.rae.es/antes)* adverb to indicate your preference.

> —¿Te vienes a hacer *puenting* con nosotros?
>   —Antes me clavo agujas en los ojos.

This would be understood but it sounds in Spanish as if you are just translating an English sentence. A more idiomatic option would be:

> —¿Te vienes a hacer *puenting* con nosotros?
>   —Antes me corto un brazo.

You can just use creativity again here. I remember the *George of the Jungle* movie in which in the Spanish version they just translated a similar sentence like this:

> —¿No querer que Úrsula amar a George?
>   —Antes preferiría que me clavaran la lengua a esa mesa a la hora de comer.

The more exaggerated the sentence the more you convey your disgust about what they told you.

> *Mas una vía sola, señora, hallo para que sin ofenderos pueda suplicaros por lo demás sin ofender a vuestra honra ni al desseo que de serviros tengo, porque sin esto antes me dexaría passar por la cruel muerte que errar un punto contra vuestra honra.*
>
> Feliciano de Silva, "Lisuarte de Grecia", 1514 (Spain).

Comment: Thanks - superb answer

Comment: @Strawberry I couldn't resist answering such a funny question. :-)

Comment: @Strawberry I have added a couple more options, but note that this answer may be quite biased towards the European Spanish. If you need answers based on the Spanish spoken in a specific American country, please specify it in your question with the appropiate tag.

Comment: Actually, if we're getting really specific, an answer employing a Catalan idiom would be even smarter

Comment: @Strawberry oh, we tried to start up a Catalan language site in the network but we couldn't get enough support. We have some active users from that region that may include a Catalan expression in their answers if they don't mind, although due to the site restrictions their answers will have to be centered in the Spanish language.

Comment: Anyway, nailing my tongue to a table with a burning nail sounds infinitely preferable to the activity my colleague had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think many of these work very well. You can't just take an unusual expression in one language and give every way of saying I wouldn't do such and such for anything at all. It's misleading....

Answer (score 0):

If the action suggested you oppose to was to be done by someone else:
"Por encima de mi cadáver"

Comment: En inglés, es "over my dead body".